# Can I reduce energy consumption if I disable accelerometer's axes?

Tags: power, accelerometer, power-consumption

I'm using [LIS3DH](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00274221.pdf) accelerometer, a 3 axes accelerometer to build a low energy consumption device. For now I just need the Y axis. If I disable X and Z, can I save more energy or the accelerometer use the same amount of power?

Comment: If you don't tell us what part you're using, there's no way anyone will be able to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable individual axes on that part with CTRL_REG1. It doesn't say that this saves power.

There's quite a lot of power-saving tips in that document, including a claimed consumption of 2uA. Probably the best thing is to put it into standby mode most of the time and use the "wake on acceleration event" feature.